# C++ Lambda/Closure Confusion - How to return a value, not a closure

Tags: c++, lambda, functional-programming, closures

I'm trying to get my head around FP in C++ and am a bit confused about the below code.

I'd like to output the value 2*a, but it appears to be outputting 'true', I guess cos the expression is being returned.

```
int main () {
    int a {5};
    std::cout << [](int a) { return 2*a; };
    return 0;
}
```

Apologies if I'm missing something stupid and obvious.

Comment: You didnt call the lambda, youre printing the lambda itself through some weird conversion, not the result of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually call the lambda using the call operator (`()`).  In this case since the lambda needs a value you would use

```
int main () {
    int a {5};
    std::cout << [](int a) { return 2*a; }(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively you can separate the two bits into

```
int main () {
    int a {5};
    auto func = [](int a) { return 2*a; };
    std::cout << func(a);
    return 0;
}
```

---

In this case since you have a non capturing lambda what is happening is the lambda is being converted to a function pointer and since that pointer is not null, true is printed.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I knew it had to be something simple.